# How to log the text in a span

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div id="myID">
    <h3 class="level-title">
     <span class="level-title-text">
        Grande Filme        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var abc = document.getElementById('myID').getElementsByClassName('level-title-text').innerHTML;

console.log(abc);
```

How do I get the text "Grande Filme" into the variable ABC?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/3mwspag9/1/)

I tried `innerText` and `value` but didn't work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work alone, [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. so you need to use first element, try this sample code

```
var abc =  document.getElementsByClassName('level-title-text')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns HTML collection so you neeed this

```
document.getElementById('myID').getElementsByClassName('level-title-text')[0].innerHTML;
```

This will return first occurrence of a given class name

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3mwspag9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You cant get a single element if you use `getElementsByClassName()`, so use `getElementById()` by giving id for span otherwise make it possible by giving array index.

```
var abc = document.getElementById('myID').getElementsByClassName('level-title-text').innerHTML[0]; //here zero is the array index

console.log(abc);
```

Or use `jquery`

```
var abc=$('#myID').children('.level-title').first().children('.level-title-text').first().val();
console.log(abc);
```